# Joining multiple tables using a loop with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a dictionary with table names and columns names, such as `input = {'demographics':['age', 'gender'], 'automobile':['aut-01'], 'flyers':['fly-00', 'fly-01']}`, the key is the table name and the value is a list of columns to extract from that table. All tables are to be joined together by the primary key `id`.

I create `tables_needed_to_load = input.keys()` and `columns_needed_to_load = input.values()`, and then I do

```
if len(tables_needed_to_load) >= 1:
    base_table = Table(tables_needed_to_load[0], metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
    base_col = [base_table.c[c] for c in columns_needed_to_load[0]]

if len(tables_needed_to_load) >= 2:
    for t, l in zip(tables_needed_to_load[1:], columns_needed_to_load[1:]):
        table = Table(t, metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
        base_col += [table.c[c] for c in l]
        j = outerjoin(base_table, table, table.c.id == base_table.c.id)

s = select(base_col).select_from(j)
result = connection.execute(s)
```

However this doesn't work. The raw SQL statement looks like this.
`SELECT demographics.age, demographics.gender, automobile."aut-01", flyers."fly-01", flyers."fly-00"
FROM automobile, demographics LEFT OUTER JOIN flyers ON flyers.id = demographics.id`. It seems like the join didn't happen to all three tables. Only flyers and demographics are joined together.